# IOError when trying to open existing files

Tags: python, file-io, ioerror, fileparsing

I have a small issue with a python program that I wrote to extract some information from a special text file. The loop (code below) needs to execute my function `extract_zcoords()` over 500 files (1 file gives one list) so that I can build a dataset.

```
import os

def extract_zcoord(filename): 
    f = open(filename, 'r')         
    ... # do something with f


### LOOP OVER DIRECTORY 
location = '/Users/spyros/Desktop/3NY8MODELSHUMAN/HomologyModels' 

for filename in os.listdir(location):
    extract_zcoord(filename)
```

---

THE ERROR: 
The IOException `No such file or directory` is the one that occurs, so for some reason python is not accessing the files. I have checked directory pathname (location) and file permissions, and they are correct (read+write). Any ideas why an IOError would be reported when the files do exist and pathname is correct?

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Can anyone think of a reason not to always use raw strings when specifying paths? Is there a downside to doing this? (*not* suggesting this as a cause of the problem, just got me thinking about minimizing potential problems with paths etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the dirname and filename into one complete path:

```
location = '/Users/spyros/Desktop/3NY8MODELSHUMAN/HomologyModels' 
for filename in os.listdir(location):
    filename = os.path.join(location, filename)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was so simple!

Answer (score 5):

Probably, you should use os.path.join when you call

```
zdata.extend(extract_zcoord(filename))
```

like this:

```
zdata.extend(extract_zcoord(os.path.join(location, filename)))
```