# weird no such file or directory in python

Tags: python, ioexception, filenotfoundexception

I'm new to `python` and the following piece of code is driving me crazy. It lists the files in a directory and for each file does some stuff. I get a `IOError: [Errno2] No such file or directory: my_file_that_is_actually_there!`

```
def loadFile(aFile):
  f_gz = gzip.open(aFile, 'rb')
  data = f_gz.read()
  #do some stuff...
  f_gz.close()
  return data

def main():
  inputFolder = '../myFolder/'
  for aFile in os.listdir(inputFolder):
    data = loadFile(aFile)
    #do some more stuff
```

The file exists and it's not corrupted. I do not understand how it's possible that python first finds the file when it checks the content of `myFolder`, and then it cannot find itanymore... This happens on the second iteration of my for loop only with any files.

***NOTE: Why does this exception happen ONLY at the second iteration of the loop?? The first file in the folder is found and opened without any issues...***

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOError when trying to open existing files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802418/ioerror-when-trying-to-open-existing-files)

Comment: Martijn, please check my edit (I added a note). This detail is not addressed in the question linked in your comment.

Comment: That can only happen if the local directory happens to have the *exact* same filename as found in `../myFolder/`. You are opening the wrong file. So if there is a `../myFolder/foo` there is *also* a `./foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `open` receives the local name (returned from `os.listdir`). It doesn't know that you mean that it should look in `../myFolder`. So it receives a relative path and applies  it to the current dir. To fix it, try:

```
data = loadFile(os.path.join(inputFolder, aFile))
```

Comment: Since `inputFolder` is a relative path, it is worth to note that it also depends on where the script is executed. This solution won't work when executed from the "wrong" directory.

Comment: When run from a "wrong" directory, the script will probably fail at the `os.listdir` stage :)

Comment: thanks, this works! But WHY does this problem arise only at the second iteration of the loop? Is there something that I have to know about python specifically?

Comment: @Gevorg It could be that the first iteration encounters a file name that happens to exist in both current directory and in `../myFolder/`.