# Error opening file - Python 3.3

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IOError when trying to open existing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802418/ioerror-when-trying-to-open-existing-files)

I'm having problems opening a file with open() in python 3.3, any idea why?

I'm trying

```
import os

filelist = [ f for f in os.listdir( os.curdir )]
singleFile = filelist[a]
hppfile = open(singleFile, 'r')
```

And I get

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-file that is actually inside the directory-'
```

Ideas?

On Windows, I just started this to learn this to write few quick scripts

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns a filename, not a full path.

Comment: `os.listdir()` already returns a list, and the default argument is already `os.curdir` btw. But I cannot reproduce this problem with files in the current directory, so I suspect your code sample does not match your real code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [Full code](http://pastebin.com/qEnHgQHP) - it's only few lines, so I'm not sure what could be wrong with it, really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [documentation for listdir](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.listdir) you will see that it returns filenames and not full path.

You will need something like

```
current_dir_path = os.getcwd()
open(os.path.join(curren_dir_path, file), 'r')
```

Comment: I already stated that in a comment, but the OP is listing the *current directory*.

Comment: So in python you need whole path to open a file? I thought it could be a relative path like in C++ is in default

Comment: @P.K.: relative paths *should* work just fine.

Comment: Oh well, that worked, no errors, thanks!